# omniauth-dropbox and dropbox-sdk, can they work together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, dropbox-api

Since I saw that the [omniauth-dropbox](https://github.com/spagalloco/omniauth-dropbox) gem, was made to:

> Authenticate to the Dropbox REST API (v1).

I was happy i wouldn't need to develop all the redirections the OAuth implies.
But I can't find a way to make them work together :(

The omniauth-dropbox gem, works fine, alone, I get authenticated and stuff.
But what to save from the callback, so the [dropbox-sdk](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/ruby) would understand the user is authenticated?

How to do so the `session.get_access_token` would be automatically handled by omniauth-dropbox?

### CODE

```rb
def dropbox
    session = DropboxSession.new(MULTIAPI_CONFIG['dropbox']['appKey'], MULTIAPI_CONFIG['dropbox']['appSecret'])
    session.get_request_token
    authorize_url = session.get_authorize_url('myurl/auth/dropbox/callback')
    print authorize_url
    session.get_access_token
    client = DropboxClient.new(session, ACCESS_TYPE)
    object = client.metadata('/')
    render :json => object
end
```

### ERROR

> Couldn't get access token.  Server returned 401: Unauthorized.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me from https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki like you can get `env['omniauth.auth']` in your callback handler, and from there you can extract the credentials (`token` and `secret`). See https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Auth-Hash-Schema.

Once you have the token and secret, you should be able to call [`session.set_access_token`](https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-ruby-sdk-1.5.1-docs/DropboxSession.html) to tell the Dropbox SDK what credentials to use.

Comment: I finally ended using only the dropbox-sdk. I will put some code in an answer. I didn't try your solution, but if someone come here, it worth a try.

Comment: I didn't accept your solution as an answer because I didn't try it, but if someone find out it does work, then I will.

Answer (score 1):

So I finally ended writing everything using the [dropbox-sdk](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/ruby)

### Controller

```rb
class DropboxController < ApplicationController

    def new
        db_session = DropboxSession.new(MULTIAPI_CONFIG['dropbox']['appKey'], MULTIAPI_CONFIG['dropbox']['appSecret'])
        begin
            db_session.get_request_token
        rescue DropboxError => e
            render template: "multi_api/home/refresh"
        end

        session[:dp_request_db_session] = db_session.serialize

        # OAuth Step 2: Send the user to the Dropbox website so they can authorize
        # our app.  After the user authorizes our app, Dropbox will redirect them
        # to our 'dp_callback' endpoint.
        auth_url = db_session.get_authorize_url url_for(:dp_callback)
        redirect_to auth_url
    end

    def destroy
        session.delete(:dp_authorized_db_session)
        render :json => checkAuth
    end

    def isAuthenticated
        render :json => checkAuth
    end

    def checkAuth
        val = {'isAuthenticated' => false}
        begin
            unless not session[:dp_authorized_db_session]
                dbsession = DropboxSession.deserialize(session[:dp_authorized_db_session])
                client = DropboxClient.new(dbsession, MULTIAPI_CONFIG['dropbox']['accessType'])
                val = {'isAuthenticated' => true}
            end
        rescue DropboxError => e
            val = {'isAuthenticated' => false}
        end
        val
    end

    def callback
        # Finish OAuth Step 2
        ser = session[:dp_request_db_session]
        unless ser
            render template: "multi_api/home/refresh"
            return
        end
        db_session = DropboxSession.deserialize(ser)

        # OAuth Step 3: Get an access token from Dropbox.
        begin
            db_session.get_access_token
        rescue DropboxError => e
            render template: "multi_api/home/refresh"
            return
        end
        session.delete(:dp_request_db_session)
        session[:dp_authorized_db_session] = db_session.serialize
        render template: "multi_api/home/refresh"
    end

end
```

### routes

```rb
get   'dp/logout', :to => 'dropbox#destroy'
get   'dp/login', :to => 'dropbox#new'
get   'dp/callback', :to => 'dropbox#callback', :as => :dp_callback
get   'dp/isAuthenticated', :to => 'dropbox#isAuthenticated'
```

### multi_api/home/refresh.html.erb

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function refreshParent()
{
  window.opener.location.reload();
  if (window.opener.progressWindow) 
    window.opener.progressWindow.close();
  window.close();
}
refreshParent();
</script>
```

### Requesting dropbox

```rb
dbsession = DropboxSession.deserialize(session[:dp_authorized_db_session])
@client = DropboxClient.new(dbsession, MULTIAPI_CONFIG['dropbox']['accessType'])
```

I open a new tab when i want to authenticate a user to dropbox, when this is done I automatically refresh the original page and close the tab (see: `multi_pi/home/refresh.html.erb`).

Since I do all of this in javascript I need to know if the user has been authenticated successfully, that's why I provided a route `dp/isAuthenticated` which will return a json string containing a `'isAuthenticated'` key set at `true` or `false`.

Connected users are not saved into a the database, only into the session. So when the session is destroyed they will have to re-authenticate. If you want them to be save into the database, then, you should dig into @smarx solution, using omniauth will be far easier.

I wrote my code here as an exemple for those who only want to depend on the [ruby dropbox-sdk](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/ruby)

Answer (score 0):

- omniauth-dropbox v0.2.0 uses the oauth1 API
- dropbox-sdk v1.5.1 uses the oauth1 API
- dropbox-sdk v1.6.1 uses the oauth2 API

With omniauth-dropbox v0.2.0 and dropbox-sdk v1.5.1, the following code in the controller action that omniauth redirects to works for me:

```
auth_hash = request.env['omniauth.auth']
access_token = auth_hash[:credentials][:token]
access_token_secret = auth_hash[:credentials][:secret]

session = DropboxSession.new(DROPBOX_APP_ID, DROPBOX_ADD_SECRET)
session.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

client = DropboxClient.new(session)
puts client.account_info.inspect
```

There might be a way to get omniauth-dropbox v0.2.0 and dropbox-sdk v1.6.1 working, but I haven't found it.

Comment: As you said, these two versions of these two libraries are incompatible, since one only supports OAuth 1 and the other only supports OAuth 2. That said, all of omniauth-dropbox is a couple dozen lines of code, and OAuth 2 is simpler than OAuth 1. You could probably start with https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-oauth2.

Answer (score 0):

As James says, the most recent version of dropbox-sdk uses oauth2, so instead of omniauth-dropbox you need to use the oauth2 strategy:

https://github.com/bamorim/omniauth-dropbox-oauth2

Then the access_token will be present in the initial oauth response (as auth.credentials.token), and you can do with it as you will in the omniauth_callbacks_controller. I store it in an Authentication object.

Answer (score 0):

For all those of you still looking for a tutorial for performing basically everything dropbox does, here's a tutorial I wrote a while ago:
http://blog.jobspire.net/dropbox-on-rails-4-0-ajax-using-dropbox-sdk/#more-54

You're welcome!